# Git tag with value containing brackets produces: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: bash, git, shell

At the company I am working for we are using a tag convention like that:

```
WhiteLabel_iOS_V.V(B)
```

Where **V** is the version and **B** is the build number. We also add the platform because we are handling different ones.

Until now, we have been using **GitKraken** and/or **SourceTree**. However, we are introducing CI/CD and I am aiming to be able to follow the same tag naming conventions. The CI/CD pipeline is done with GitHub actions and it uses a ruby module that execute all the sh actions using **system**

Using the sh command on the terminal:

```
git tag –a WhiteLabel_iOS_3.9(3) -m “WhiteLabel_iOS_3.9(3)”
```

produces the following error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

However, executing it like that:

```
git tag –a WhiteLabel_iOS_3.9\(3\) -m "WhiteLabel_iOS_3.9(3)"
```

It seems to work.

I have tried the following command in Ruby:

```
success = system("git tag –a WhiteLabel_iOS_3.9\(3\)")
```

But it doesn't work...

Any ideas?

Comment: The reason for this is that parentheses are significant to, and hence interpreted by, the shell, long before Git ever has a chance to see them. The shell tries to make sense of the `(3)` part and can't, and never runs `git` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use quotes:

```
git tag –a "WhiteLabel_iOS_3.9(3)" -m "WhiteLabel_iOS_3.9(3)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'success' command is missing a closing parenthesis.

it should rather look like this;

```
success = system("git tag –a WhiteLabel_iOS_3.9\(3\)")
```

Comment: After fixing the possible bug, still not working

Answer (score 0):

If using system in ruby, then:

```
tag_name = "WhiteLabel_iOS_3.9(4)"
success = system("git tag -a \"#{tag_name}\" -m \"#{tag_name}\"; git push origin \"#{tag_name}\"")
```